# Django manage.py can't find an INSTALLED_APP even though the module is in the path

Tags: python, django, django-evolution

When I run python manage.py shell I get an error about the last app I've added to INSTALLED_APPS, namely django-evolution, saying it's an undefined module. This is despite the fact that I've added the path to django-evolution to the system path. In fact right after this error I can run python and do an import on django_evolution and everything is fine. Why isn't django or python seeing this module when clearly it's been setup and even added to the path?

EDIT:

This only happens when running from iPython. When I run from the cmd prompt it works fine. Go figure.

Answer (score 1):

Does your `django_evolution` have a **init**.py file in it?  Also any folder containing `django_evolution` needs one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add it to your INSTALLED_APPS section of settings.py.

Comment: I did. It's precisely that line in settings.py that is failing. Sorry I miscommunicated that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using virtualenv and ipython is installed at the system level but your app at the env level, it will lead to this. The way out of it is to remove ipython from the system and to install it into your env.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is super old, but in case anyone has this issue, my issue was because I had elevated to root inside my venv. I had initialized my virtual environment, and then upgraded my privileges to root. If `deactivate` doesn't work and you're root, then you should `exit` then `deactivate`, then you can do `sudo su` and then `source myenv/bin/activate`. Hope this helps!